# Make Windows Forms Application (C#) installer (?) - Deploy to other users/computers

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I have made a windows forms application that is working how i want it. It can create SharePoint Lists from a desktop, fill in important parameters and at the end of the say, it becomes a form that can be published to SharePoint. This all works fine. Now i'm ready to package it up and make it deployable to other users and computers.

This seems pretty straightforward for your plain vanilla program but since i'm referencing other DLL's and have XML files that the program uses, I'm assuming i'm going to need to make some sort of installer.  However, the threads that I'm reading seem very long and contridictive. My question is more of a general question about how to make the project compiled and passed around the other computers. Do i need to make an installer or is there an easier way to just gather the correct dependencies and place them into a single folder and pass that around.

At a high level: how do i make my windows forms application deployable to any user? Would I create a new visual studio project just to do this?

Comment: Is your Forms app installed only by and for Standard Users, or will it require Admin access or elevation?

Comment: The current supported techniques for Visual Studio are ClickOnce or a third-party approach like Wix (http://wixtoolset.org/) or InstallShield. Of course, you could always just put all the files in a .zip, tell your users to drop the contents to a directory somewhere, and have them create whatever shortcuts they want manually (if any).

Comment: admin access isn't required since the application itself gathers credentials. If they don't have access to SharePoint, that's an external issue.

Comment: Given your comments I would suggest [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: We have been using Inno Setup for many years be now, and we love it. Very easy to setup a simple installer, but also very flexible if you need more complicated stuff later on.